# Test that two std::vectors are equal using CATCH C++ unit test framework

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, catch-unit-test

I an new to using CATCH, and I wondering how one would go about testing whether two `std::vectors` are equal.

My very naive attempt is this:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
#include <vector>

TEST_CASE( "are vectors equal", "vectors")
{
  std::vector<int> vec_1 = {1,2,3};
  std::vector<int> vec_2 = {1,2,3};

  REQUIRE (vec_1.size() == vec_2.size());

  for (int i = 0; i < vec_1.size(); ++i)
    REQUIRE (vec_1[i] == vec_2[i]);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Some thing like magic `REQUIRE_VECTOR_EQUAL`?

Also, my above solution, is passing if one array contained doubles `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`; It's fine if two vectors are not considered equal because of this.

Comment: You may still do `REQUIRE(vec_1 == vec_2);`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, thank you, this does work. The only thing is that if `vec_1` and `vec_2` are of different data types I get an error, instead of, say `false`.

Comment: @Akavall It's won't compile if they are of different data types. That's how a strongly typed language is supposed to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [operator==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp):

```
REQUIRE(vec_1 == vec_2)
```

The cool thing is that Catch produces fantastic output when the assertion fails, and not just a simple pass/fail:

```
../test/Array_Vector_Test.cpp:90: FAILED:
  CHECK( x == y )
with expansion:
  { "foo", "bar" }
  ==
  { "foo", "quux", "baz" }
```

Comment: Note: You can inline the vector also REQUIRE( split(input) == std::vector<string>{"one", "two", "three"});